# pyparsing.operatorPrecedence not raising an error on an invalid string

Tags: python, pyparsing

I wish to parse a string representing a boolean expression. The following code is based on many examples and uses pyparsing's operatorPrecedence helper.

The problem is that it I would like the code to raise an exception when the string cannot be sensibly parsed. As it stands, many invalid expressions just pass quietly and the wrong expression is returned.

```
import pyparsing

_A = pyparsing.Literal('A')
_B = pyparsing.Literal('B')

bool_operand = pyparsing.Or((_A, _B))

precedence_list = [("NOT", 1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
        ("AND", 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
        ("OR", 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),]

bool_parser = pyparsing.operatorPrecedence(bool_operand, precedence_list)

print bool_parser.parseString('A OR B OR NOT A') # A valid string
print bool_parser.parseString('A NOT AND B') # an invalid string
```

This outputs:

```
[['A', 'OR', 'B', 'OR', ['NOT', 'A']]]
['A']
```

So the first string works, but the second string does not raise an exception as desired.

Any ideas how I can do this? I'm not particularly familiar with pyparsing, so I could have missed something there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your definitions of A_ and B_ to use the `Keyword` class instead of the `Literal` class.

Also, when you call parseString, add `parseAll=True` so that you force the entire input to be parsed.